# Error 500 when using "WWW", [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down

Tags: ubuntu, apache2

I get Error 500 when I try to load one of my sites with "www".

www.catherinesmith.net

Without www, it works fine. I have multiple sites hosted using vhosts. I have ruled out the vhost config by deleting it and replacing it with another site that is working fine, then substituting in the domain.

`[Wed Aug 28 20:56:06 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down`

`[Wed Aug 28 20:56:07 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.7 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming no$`

I have also ruled out any of the files in the site folder by deleting everything and making index.php with "HI" in it.

I also just disabled the site vhost, so it should just point to the main IP (which just lists the hosted sites). catherinesmith.net loads fine, but www.catherinesmith.net still gives error 500! I'm pulling my hair out over this one. I have no idea what's causing this or what else I can try...

VHost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/catherinesmith.net

    #Custom
    ServerName catherinesmith.net
    ServerAlias www.catherinesmith.net
    php_admin_value open_basedir /var/www/catherinesmith.net/:/tmp/
    #Custom

    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/catherinesmith.net/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
</Directory>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oddly enough, I left the computer for a while and it fixed itself. I assume this might have been a problem with Rackspace. If I ever find out what it was, or if the problem returns, I'll try to post details here.

Answer (score 0):

How do you set up your virtual host for the www/without alias?

Just looked at mine and I have it set like this example: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html#intraextra

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.1 172.20.30.40>
    DocumentRoot /www/server1
    ServerName server.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

What is surprising is the SIGTERM/restart as an error even if the virtual host definition is the issue.

Comment: I added the vhost. I don't get how it could be the vhost because it's the exact same set-up as I have for 2 other sites, but I'm really not sure what else it could be because theres not much to a vhost other than the config and web folder.

Comment: If you switch servername/alias, does it fail in the other way?

Comment: It doesn't change anything. If I can't get it fixed in a few days I'll just backup all the files and reload the server from a fresh image. The funny thing is, even when I disable the vhost so the domain just points to my server ip, it still fails the exact same way when I use www...